# Create jinja template from dictionary in ansible

Tags: dictionary, templates, ansible, jinja2

how can I access stdout and item values in a dictionary?

My inventory file:

```
all:
  hosts:
    server1:
      dict:
        custom_mountpoints:
          - /srv/sftp
          - /opt
    server2:
       dict:
        custom_mountpoints:
          - /srv/sftp
          - /opt
```

My ansible task:

```
- name: Genarate OIDs for custom inventroy variables
  become: yes
  shell: 'snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.\"{{ item[1] }}-{{ item[0] }}\"'
  loop: "{{ dict.custom_mountpoints | product(snmp_mountpoints_extends) | list }}"

  register: custom_mountpoints_output
  when:
    - dict is defined

- name: print output from custom_mountpoints_output
  debug: msg={{ custom_mountpoints_output }}
```

Output from custom_mountpoints_output variable:

```
ok: [server01] =>
 msg:
   changed: true
   msg: All items completed
   results:
   - ansible_loop_var: item
     changed: true
     cmd: snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.\"folder-size-/srv/sftp\"
     delta: '0:00:00.015394'
     end: '2022-04-28 11:40:29.130234'
     failed: false
     invocation:
       module_args:
         _raw_params: snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.\"folder-size-/srv/sftp\"
         _uses_shell: true
         argv: null
         chdir: null
         creates: null
         executable: null
         removes: null
         stdin: null
         stdin_add_newline: true
         strip_empty_ends: true
         warn: false
     item:
     - /srv/sftp
     - folder-size
     rc: 0
     start: '2022-04-28 11:40:29.114840'
     stderr: ''
     stderr_lines: []
     stdout: .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.21.102.111.108.100.101.114.45.115.105.122.101.45.47.115.114.118.47.115.102.116.112
     stdout_lines:
     - .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.21.102.111.108.100.101.114.45.115.105.122.101.45.47.115.114.118.47.115.102.116.112
```

etc. for each snmp_mountpoints_extends

then I try to access only stdout value:

```
- name: print output from custom_mountpoints_output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  loop: "{{ custom_mountpoints_output.results }}"
  register: output
```

become the following output:

```
ok: [server1] => (item={'cmd': 'snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.\\"folder-size-/srv/sftp\\"', 'stdout': '.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1
.3.2.3.1.1.21.102.111.108.100.101.114.45.115.105.122.101.45.47.115.114.118.47.115.102.116.112', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2022-04-28 11:40:29.114840', 'end': '2022-04-28 11:40:29.130234', 'delta': '0:00:00.015394', 'changed': True, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': 'snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.\\"folder-size-/srv/sftp\\"', '_uses_shell': True, 'warn': False, 'stdin_add_newline': True, 'strip_empty_ends': True, 'argv': None, 'chdir': None, 'executable': None, 'creates': None, 'removes': None, 'stdin': None}}, 'stdout_lines': ['.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.21.102.111.108.100.101.114.45.115.105.122.101.45.47.115.114.118.47.115.102.116.112'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False, 'item': ['/srv/sftp', 'folder-size'], 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) =>
  msg: .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.21.102.111.108.100.101.114.45.115.105.122.101.45.47.115.114.118.47.115.102.116.112
ok: [server1] => (item={'cmd': 'snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.\\"folder-avail-/srv/sftp\\"', 'stdout': '.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.22.102.111.108.100.101.114.45.97.118.97.105.108.45.47.115.114.118.47.115.102.116.112', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2022-04-28 11:40:29.605138', 'end': '2022-04-28 11:40:29.620156', 'delta': '0:00:00.015018', 'changed': True, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': 'snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.\\"folder-avail-/srv/sftp\\"', '_uses_shell': True, 'warn': False, 'stdin_add_newline': True, 'strip_empty_ends': True, 'argv': None, 'chdir': None, 'executable': None, 'creates': None, 'removes': None, 'stdin': None}}, 'stdout_lines': ['.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.22.102.111.108.100.101.114.45.97.118.97.105.108.45.47.115.114.118.47.115.102.116.112'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False, 'item': ['/srv/sftp', 'folder-avail'], 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) =>
  msg: .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.22.102.111.108.100.101.114.45.97.118.97.105.108.45.47.115.114.118.47.115.102.116.112
```

etc.

But i would like to create a jinja template that write for me the following output in the file:

```
Hostname from a inventory file
 /srv/sftp\
 folder-size
 extend: value of stdout (.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.21.102.111.108.100.101.114.45.115.105.122.101.45.47.115.114.118.47.115.102.116.112)
```

I try with following code:

```
{% for i in groups['all'] %}
Servername:  {{ hostvars[i].inventory_hostname }}
 {% for dict_item in output %}
   {% for item in dict_item.values() %}
 {{ item.value.msg }}
   {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% for item in output.values() %}
 Extend: {{ output[item].stdout }}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it didn't work. Any idea how can i implement this with ansible and jinja?

Comment: why do you create the output variabile? i mean why don't you use directly custom_mountpoints_output.results -> item.stdout as you do inside the debug?

Comment: same thing I become "  msg: 'AnsibleUndefinedVariable: dict object has no element"

Comment: I think your problem is that [`dict` is Jinja global function](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-globals.dict), which you should not use as a variable name. Use something expressive instead

Comment: I use the dict variable in my inventory file:
```
all:
  hosts:
    server1:
      dict:
        custom_mountpoints:
          - /srv/sftp
          - /opt
    server2:
       dict:
        custom_mountpoints:
          - /srv/sftp
          - /opt
```

Comment: Please don't spread needed info to answer your question over volatile comments. Edit your question instead.